Counting words that agree at some place with each of their cyclic permutations
Let $a(m,n)$ be the number of words $W$ of length $m$ in an alphabet of $n$ letters, which have the property that each cyclic permutation of $W,$ has the same letter as $W$ in some place.
For example, $aabcb$ counts (for $m=5$ and $n\ge 3$), since its cyclic permutations $baabc,$ $cbaab,$ $bcbaa,$ $abcba,$ agree with it at places 2, 5, 3, 1. But $aabbc$ does not count, because it disagrees with $bcaab$ everywhere.
Some values of $a(m,n)$ for small $m$ are as follows:
$a(1,n)=a(2,n)=n$
$a(3,n)=n(3n-2)$
$a(4,n)=n(4n-3)$
$a(5,n)=n+15n(n-1)^2$
$a(6,n)=n+3n(n-1)^2(4n+1)$
$a(7,n)=n+7n(n−1)(2n^3+5n^2−29n+31)$
$a(8,n)=n+4n(n−1)(24n^3−66n^2+37n+27)$
$a(9,n)=n+3n(n−1)(87n^4−369n^3+292n^2+811n−1145)$
The formulae for $m\ge 5$ are due to Fabius Wiesner (see comments).
It thus appears that $a(m,n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ for each $m.$ (This is clear in fact - see below.)
Is a general formula for $a(m,n)$ known?
Incidental remark: When $m$ is prime, the action of the cyclic group of order $m$ on the set of counted words shows that $(a(m,n)-n)/m$ is an integer. When $m=5$ this ratio is $3n(n-1)^2,$ which is also the number of 2 x 2 planar subsets of a 3 x 3 cube (OEIS sequence A270205). This is probably a coincidence, but I mention it in case there is a nice reason.
Based on Fabius Wiesner's notes (see comments below) it may be more enlightening to write
$$a(m,n)=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}b(m,r)\left(\begin{matrix}n\\r\end{matrix}\right)$$ where $b(m,r)=\sum_{s=1}^r(-1)^{r-s}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}r\\s\end{smallmatrix}\right)a(m,s)$ is the number of words with the given property, that use exactly all the first $r$ letters in the alphabet. The expression for $b(m,r)$ is the inclusion-exclusion formula. Then the formulae above become:
$a(1,n)=a(2,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(3,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+6\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(4,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+8\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(5,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+30\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)
+90\left(\begin{matrix}n\\3\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(6,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+54\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)
+306\left(\begin{matrix}n\\3\end{matrix}\right)+288\left(\begin{matrix}n\\4\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(7,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+126\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)+1428\left(\begin{matrix}n\\3\end{matrix}\right)+3864\left(\begin{matrix}n\\4\end{matrix}\right)+1680\left(\begin{matrix}n\\5\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(8,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+232\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)+3912\left(\begin{matrix}n\\3\end{matrix}\right)+14400\left(\begin{matrix}n\\4\end{matrix}\right)+11520\left(\begin{matrix}n\\5\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(9,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+510\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)+16470\left(\begin{matrix}n\\3\end{matrix}\right)+126432\left(\begin{matrix}n\\4\end{matrix}\right)+305640\left(\begin{matrix}n\\5\end{matrix}\right)+187920\left(\begin{matrix}n\\6\end{matrix}\right)$
$a(10,n)=\left(\begin{matrix}n\\1\end{matrix}\right)+990\left(\begin{matrix}n\\2\end{matrix}\right)+45630\left(\begin{matrix}n\\3\end{matrix}\right)+460200\left(\begin{matrix}n\\4\end{matrix}\right)+1506000\left(\begin{matrix}n\\5\end{matrix}\right)+1605600\left(\begin{matrix}n\\6\end{matrix}\right)+403200\left(\begin{matrix}n\\7\end{matrix}\right)$
This formulation makes it clear why $a(m,n)$ is a polynomial in $n,$ and shows that it would be enough to determine $b(m,r)$ for $1\le r<m.$ It would be interesting to know just the degree of the polynomial, i.e. to understand when $b(m,r)=0.$ See comments for some remarks on this question.
Remark: Factorizing the $b(m,r)$ The group $C_m\times S_r$ acts on the words counted by $b(m,r).$ For $r>1,$ the orbits are mostly regular; this must hold when $m$ is prime, so that $b(m,r)$ is divisible by $m\cdot r!$ for $m$ prime and $r>1;$ for example $b(7,4)=3864=7\cdot 4!\cdot 23.$ But for example, $b(6,2)$ is not divisible by $12$ and $b(6,3)$ is not divisible by $36;$ the words $aabaab$ and $aabaac$ have nontrivial stabilizers in $C_6\times S_2$ and $C_6\times S_3$ respectively.

Hopefully without errors, I have computed $a(6,n)-n=3n(n-1)^2(4n-1)$, $a(7,n)-n=7n(n-1)(2n^3+5n^2-29n+31)$, $a(8,n)-n=4n(n-1)(24n^3-66n^2+37n+27)$, $a(9,n)-n=3n(n-1)(87n^4-369n^3+292n^2+811n-1145)$. Therefore the degree is $5 \not= m-2$ for $m=8$ and $6 \not= m-2$ for $m=9$, unless I made mistakes.

@FabiusWiesner I find $a(6,n)-n=3n(n-1)^2(4n+1),$ but I agree with your polynomials for $m=7$ and $m=8,$ and so also with your conclusion about the degree. I have edited the question for that. Shall I also add your polynomials - if so, do you agree about $a(6,n)$?

Yes you are right it is $4n+1$, sorry. Regarding the degrees of $a(m,n)-n$ they agree with A064726 "Sum of primes dividing the partitions of n into distinct parts (with repetition)" but probably a coincidence.

Don't know if you know already, and it is not much, but since a word that has at least half letters equal must agree somewhere for any permutation, we have a (not tight) lower bound ${m \choose \lceil (m+1)/2 \rceil}n(n-1)^{\lfloor (m-1)/2 \rfloor}$ and thus a lower bound for the degree is $\lceil (m+1)/2 \rceil$. However, e.g. for $m=5$ we need to count also words of the form $aaaaa$ ($n$) and $abccb$ ($5n(n-1)^2$) to get the correct result, and for $m \gt 5$ there are probably much more forms to evaluate. I don't know if there is a way to enumerate all of them.

I have computed that, in addition to the words that have at least half letters equal, there are $0,1,9,36,141$ classes of isomorphic words satisfying the requirement (up to a letter replacement and a cyclic permutation) for $m=4,5,6,7,8$ respectively. Among these, those contributing a term with maximum degree are $aabcb$ ($\equiv abccb$) for $m=5$, $aabacd$ and $aabcad$ for $m=6$, $aabacde$ and $aabcdae$ for $m=7$.

If we count for a binary word of length $m$ the minimum number of ones satisfying the requirement, apparently we get OEIS A283297 and this mathoverflow question. If the connection is correct, from there we get a lower bound for the degree of: $m-\sqrt{2m}+1$ (except for $m=4$).

@FabiusWiesner In relation to the degree of $a(m,n)-n$ as a polynomial in $n,$ despite agreement with [A064726] (https://oeis.org/A064726) for $m\le 9$ (your comment above), I don't think this sequence gives the right degree for all $n.$ As $a(2m,n)\ge a(m,n)$ for all $n$ because of the map $w\mapsto ww$ of words, so the degree for words of length $2m$ is not less than the degree for $m,$ but the sequence has $a(30)=43$ and $a(60)=36.$ From the degrees for $m\le 9$ perhaps the degree steps up by $1$ from $m-1$ to $m$ except when $m$ is a power of $2.$

On the degree, say $d_m,$ of $a(m,n)$ in $n,$ we have $d_m\ge m-\sqrt{2m}+1$ from the connection you explain in your comment. For a similar upper bound let $w$ be a word of length $m$ with the given property, using exactly $r$ letters with multiplicities $\mu_1\ge\dots\ge\mu_r\ge 1,$ $\sum \mu_i=m.$ $d_m$ is the largest such $r.$ Then $w$ and a nontrivial rotation agree at a letter $i$ at most $\mu_i(\mu_i-1)$ times, so $\sum\mu_i(\mu_i-1)\ge m-1.$ The LHS is maximized when $\mu_1=m-r+1$ and $\mu_2=\cdots=\mu_r=1,$ so $(m-r+1)(m-r)\ge m-1,$ i.e. $d_m\le m+\tfrac 12-\sqrt{m-\tfrac 34}.$
